# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

XAMPP 3.3.0
MySql port: 3306
I checked any conflict with this port and found nothing

MySql doesn't respond to any request, infinite loading and after that it shuts down leaving no error logs

XAMPP logs:

```
    21:05:56  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    21:05:56  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    21:05:56  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    21:05:56  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    21:05:56  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    21:05:56  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
    21:05:56  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

```
MySql server logs:

 1. 2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
    Windows interlocked functions
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
    1.2.11
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total
    size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
    buffer pool
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback
    segments are active.
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for
    temporary tables
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file
    'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the
    file full; Please wait ...
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: File
    'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence
    number 3046387; transaction id 1396
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
    C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    
    2022-06-18 21:07:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hello!**

*Just do these simple steps:*

- Rename the folder ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data`*** to ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data_old`***
  (or any name)
- Create new folder ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data`***
- Copy the content that is inside ***`C:\xampp\mysql\backup`*** to
  ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data`*** folder
- Copy all your database folders that are in ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data_old`*** to
  ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data`*** (skip performance_schema, mysql and
  phpmyadmin folders from ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data_old`***)
- Finally copy the ibdata1 file from ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data_old`*** and
  replace it inside ***`C:\xampp\mysql\data`*** folder
- Now Restart MySQL from XAMPP control panel.

And I am sure its all done...

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should copying these files resolve the problem?

Comment: this thing you explained worked like charm, but can you explain why this thing happened? I am asking this because I was using this mysql from last 3 years, nothing changed during this time in my PC, i use just use it as server. but today it showing me same error so I tried this solution, and it WORKED. but please explain if you can.
Thank you sir.

Comment: @imad Ullah, i am haveing strange issue, it worked, but if I restart pc, it again showing same error, and same error log.

Comment: Surely, I am updating the answer...

Comment: @ImadUllah , I have to do this every now and then
2 days, Is there a better way to limit it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and i fixed it by deleting all master-xx.info files and the multi-master.info file in C:\xampp\mysql\data

After I started it again it made a new and empty multi-master.info file and it worked perfectly fine again. No Data was lost

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to CMD
Write
Services.msc
Find myql on the panel that comes up
Stop it

Enjoy